# how to get external form validation to work with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Okay, I'm trying to get a contact form to work and it is, sort of. The data is passing through, but I can't get the jQuery to work. If I type in two different email addresses it doesn't catch it. Here is the relevant code I used:

HTML

```
<aside>
    <form action="sendmail.php" method="post" name="contact_form" id="contact_form">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>sign up now!</legend><br>
        <p>Sign up for my email list and get a free mini coloring book!</p><br>
        <img src="Images/minicoloirngbook.jpg" alt="mini coloring book"><br>
        <label for="name"> Name:</label>
        <input type="text"name="name" id="name" required><span>*</span><br>
        <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required><span>*</span><br>
        <label for="verify">Verify Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="verify" id="verify" required> <span>*</span><br>
        <div id="buttons">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Sign Up">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</aside>
```

and here is the Javascript:

```
$("#contact_form").submit(event => {
     let isValid = true;
     
  // validate the first name entry
const name = $("#name").val().trim();
    if (name == "") {
      $("#name").next().text("This field is required.");
      isValid = false;
    } else {
      $("#name").next().text("");
    }
    $("#name").val(name);


// validate the email entry with a regular expression
const emailPattern = /\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b/;
    const email = $("#email").val().trim();
        if (email == "") { 
            $("#email").next().text("This field is required.");
            isValid = false;
        } else if ( !emailPattern.test(email) ) {
         $("#email").next().text("Must be a valid email address.");
         isValid = false;
        } else {
            $("#email").next().text("");
        }
         $("#email").val(email);
    
    // validate the verify entry
const verify = $("#verify").val().trim();
    if (verify == "") { 
        $("#verify").next().text("This field is required.");
        isValid = false; 
    } else if (verify !== email) { 
        $("#verify").next().text("Must match first email entry.");
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        $("#verify").next().text("");
    }
    $("#verify").val(verify);
  
                
    // prevent the submission of the form if any entries are invalid 
    if (isValid == false) {
        event.preventDefault();                
    }
}),
```

I think that the answer is probably something really simple that I can't see and would appreciate your help in figuring it out.

Comment: Where's your problem ? I just removed `required` attribute and your code is working fine + also at the end of your js code there's a comma it's cause an error remove it

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Here is the jsfiddle if you like to play with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/xk6ez3aq/7/

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  var name = $("#a").val();
  if (name == "") {
    $("#nameerror").text("This field is required.");
    alert('false');
  } else {
    alert('true');
    $("#nameerror").remove();
  }

  //email1
  var emailPattern = /\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b/;
  const email = $("#b").val();
  if (email == "") {
    $("#email1error").text("This field is required.");
    isValid = false;
  } else if (!emailPattern.test(email)) {
    $("#email1error").text("Must be a valid email address.");
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    $("#email1error").remove();
  }

  //eamil 2
  var verify = $("#c").val();
  if (verify == "") {
    $("#email2error").text("This field is required.");
    isValid = false;
  } else if (verify !== email) {
    $("#email2error").text("Must match first email entry.");
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    $("#email2error").remove();
  }

  if (isValid == false) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="javascript:alert('ok')">
  <label for="name"> Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="a"><span>*</span>
  <div id="nameerror"></div><br>
  <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="b"><span>*</span>
  <div id="email1error"></div><br>
  <label for="verify">Verify Email:</label>
  <input type="text" name="verify" id="c"> <span>*</span>
  <div id="email2error"></div><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<div></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, but it still didn't work for me, I don't know what I'm doing wrong @Bernhard Betus

Comment: Maybe the action sendmail.php is the problem. Because you are sending the form to a php script. So you get $_POST variables by name attribute in your sendmail.php. For example $_POST['name']. Why are you don't use a JQuery validation plugin. It's easer and saver.